# Is it possible to have predefined text in Twitter?

Tags: ios, twitter

I have implemented Twitter into my iPhone application. I was just wondering if it is possible for me to have predefined text in my textfield everytime I want to tweet something.

Comment: Have you even searched the web for that question? And your issue doesn't really have a link with twitter but only iOS API and TextField

Answer (score 0):

Sure, as long as you store that pre-defined text somewhere you can access it when you need to.

```
-(void)tweetSomething {
    [tweet withText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tweeting! #%@",[self myApp]]];
    /* [self myApp] can be something you have stored somewhere else */
}

-(NSString *)myApp {
    /* define your own plist file */
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[plist objectForKey:@"kMyPredefinedTweetText"]];
}
```